# Change color is not working in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I set Foreground in Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ValueStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SubHeadingFontStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>       
    **<Setter Property="v:DynamicProperties.ForegroundKey" Value="{Binding Color, Mode=OneWay, Converter={v:SignalColorToResourceKeyConverter}}" />**
</Style>
```

I have DataTemplete:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vs:NumericVisualizerElement}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="AverageValue"
               **Style="{StaticResource ValueStyle}"**
               Text="{Binding Path=AverageValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        **<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Color}" Value="None">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>**
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

In v:SignalColorToResourceKeyConverter if Color is "None" then return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. But i want Foreground is Red when Color is None.
When first load is Color is None then Foreground has Red, but when i change Color at runtime then return Color is None, Foreground is not Red, that it is UnsetValue. How to fix it ?
Thanks for helping me !

Edit 1:
I define enum SignalColor

```
 public enum SignalColor
{
    None,
    Signal01A,
    Signal02A,
    Signal03A,
}
```

and method **Convert** in SignalColorToResourceKeyConverter.cs:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type tagertType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var signalColor = (SignalColor) value;

        switch (signalColor)
        {
            case SignalColor.None:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            case SignalColor.Signal01A:
                return "Signal01ABrush";
            case SignalColor.Signal01B:
                return "Signal01BBrush";
        }
     }
```

i want when i choose color is None, foreground will override is Red. I want to do this in file xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
Xaml Code:

```
Foreground="{Binding RowForeColor,
 Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"
```

Converter Code

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((string)value == "Red")
        {
            return "Red";
        }
        else  if((string)value == "White")
        {
            return "White";
        }
        else if ((string)value == "LightGray")
        {
            return "LightGray";
        }
        else if((string)value =="Pink")
        {
            return "Pink";
        }
        return "Black";
    }
```

Comment: I want to do this in file xaml.